# The complex unit (open or closed) disk as a group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, geometry

I tried to search some literature on this specific argument, but didn't find anything really up to the point and well written. The questions I'm interested in are: 
- what are the (relevant) operations which form a group with the unit disk?
- are these groups somehow important in geometry or in algebra?

Any reference is wellcome.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean a group whose *underlying subset* is the unit disk, i.e. the group elements are the point in the unit disc? Or instead so you mean a group *acting* on the unit disk?

Comment: @LeeMosher I think he's asking if there's any binary operation $\cdot$ that makes the unit disk a group. For example I've thought about multiplication, but then $0$ doesn't have inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the subgroup of [Mobius transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) that sends the unit circle to the unit circle (and the inside of the unit circle to the inside of the unit circle).

Now let $z$ in the open unit circle represent a Mobius transformation that takes $0$ to $z$. This becomes a group. Well, almost. Because the complex number $0$ can represent any rotation, and similarily, an arbitrary $z$ can represent a transformation $f$ but also $f$ preceeded by any rotation, we need to narrow it down further. So what we need is the subgroup of Mobius transformations that preserve the unit disc and fixes a single point on the unit circle, like, for instance, $1$.

Comment: There is no Mobius transformation that preserves $\pm 1$ and that sends the origin to a point not on the segment $(-1,1) \times \{0\}$.

Comment: I think probably there is no group structure on the open unit disc which preserves the conformal structure.

Comment: @LeeMosher I think it's fixed now.

Comment: Ah, I like that, of course! My previous comment on "no group structure" was nonsense.

Comment: And by the way, we can name this group, by looking at it from the upper half space point of view, where $1$ on the unit circle corresponds to $\infty$ in the upper half plane: this is the group of $\mathbb{R}$-affine self-maps of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

The map
$$f:\quad {\mathbb C}\to D,\qquad z\mapsto w:={z\over 1+|z|}$$
with inverse
$$f^{-1}:\quad D\to{\mathbb C},\qquad w\mapsto z:={w\over 1+|w|}$$
is a homeomorphism from ${\mathbb C}\sim{\mathbb R}^2$ to the open unit disk $D\subset{\mathbb C}$. Now transport the addition in ${\mathbb C}$ to $D$ using $f$. This turns $D$ into an additive group. In terms of a formula: For $u$, $v\in D$ define
$$u\oplus v:=f\bigl(f^{-1}(u)+f^{-1}(v)\bigr)\ .$$